# Python - how to handle outcome variables that are conditional set correctly

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```
    def funcA():
        some process = dynamicVar
        if dynamicVar == 1:
            return dynamicVar
        else:
            print "no dynamicVar"

    def main():
        outcome = funcA()
```

If the 'some process' part results in a 1, the var dynamicVar is passed back as `outcome` to the main func. If dynamicVar is anything but 1, the routine fails as no arguments are being return.

I could wrap the outcome as a list:

```
    def funcA():
        outcomeList = []
        some process = dynamicVar
        if dynamicVar == 1:
            outcomeList.append(dynamicVar)
            return outcomeList
        else:
            print "no dynamicVar"
            return outcomeList

    def main():
        outcome = funcA()
        if outcome != []:
            do something using dynamicVar
        else:
            do something else!
```

or maybe as a dictionary item. Each of the 2 solutions I can think of involve another set of processing in the main / requesting func.

Is this the 'correct' way to handle this eventuality? or is there a better way?

What is the proper way of dealing with this. I was particularly thinking about trying to catch `try:` / `except:` errors, so in that example the uses are reversed, so something along the lines of:

```
    def funcA():
        some process = dynamicVar
        if dynamicVar == 1:
            return
        else:
            outcome = "no dynamicVar"
            return outcome 

    def main():
        try:
            funcA()
        except:
            outcome = funcA.dynamicVar
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? If you don't return anything, you return `None`.

Comment: I added the problem I was trying to fix as an example

Comment: @JayGattuso how does "the routine fail", exactly? the code you posted is perfectly ok to my eyes...

Comment: @deathApril if `dynamicVar` does = 1, there is no returning argument for `outcome` (in `main()`) to be assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when you write a function, it's return value should be clear and expected. You should return what you say you will return. That being said, you can use `None` as a meaningful return value to indicate that the operation failed or produced no results:

```
def doSomething():
    """
    doSomething will return a string value 
    If there is no value available, None will be returned
    """
    if check_something():
        return "a string"

    # this is being explicit. If you did not do this,
    # None would still be returned. But it is nice
    # to be verbose so it reads properly with intent.   
    return None
```

Or you can make sure to always return a default of the same type:

```
def doSomething():
    """
    doSomething will return a string value 
    If there is no value available, and empty string 
    will be returned
    """
    if check_something():
        return "a string"

    return ""
```

This handles the case with a bunch of complex conditional tests that eventually just fall through:

```
def doSomething():
    if foo:
        if bar:
            if biz:
                return "value"
    return ""
```

Comment: Thats a very clear example of what I was trying to describe. Thank you. Very helpful to me!

Answer (score 3):

In Python, all function that do not return a value will implicitly return `None`. So you can just check `if outcome is not None` in `main()`.

Comment: Ahh, OK! I can just return the object `None` and evaluate for that. So simple, thank you.